# Putting message into azure queue

Tags: python, azure

I follow the details given for putting the message into an azure queue from  [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python). When I try to put a message into queue,

```
from azure.storage import QueueService
queue_service = QueueService(account_name, account_key)
queue_service.put_message('taskqueue', 'Hello world!')
```

a message is put in the queue but it is empty. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: to make sure  addd queue_service.create_queue('taskqueue') before your put_message

Comment: i did that too. but always i see an empty message in the queue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python#insert-a-message-into-a-queue) needs an update. We need to encode the string which is missing from the docs.

Below code, I tested and worked for me:

```
    from azure.storage.queue import (
           QueueClient,
           BinaryBase64EncodePolicy,
           BinaryBase64DecodePolicy
    )
    ...
    queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(
        AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING,
        QUEUE_NAME
        )

    # Setup Base64 encoding and decoding functions
    queue_client.message_encode_policy = BinaryBase64EncodePolicy()
    queue_client.message_decode_policy = BinaryBase64DecodePolicy()

    message = 'Hello World'
    message_bytes = message.encode('ascii')
    queue_client.send_message(
      queue_client.message_encode_policy.encode(content=message_bytes)
      )
```

- We can not use the string directly with neither **queue_client.message_encode_policy.encode**  nor even plain **base64.b64encode('hello')** methods because a byte liked object is needed.

  ```
    In [6]: base64.b64encode('hello')
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-b1f43373737a> in <module>
    ----> 1 base64.b64encode('hello')
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/base64.py in b64encode(s, altchars)
    ...
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
  ```
- Plus the above code is using the [latest SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python#send-message-content----kwargs-) the method name changed.
- Everything is tested under Python 3.9

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a case of this, it worked like this.

`message = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(custom_logentry).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')`

Later on I found an equivalent method of setting the QueueService instance's encoding function

```
from azure.storage.queue import QueueService, QueueMessageFormat
queue_service = QueueService(account_name, account_key)
queue_service.encode_function = QueueMessageFormat.text_base64encode
queue_service.put_message('taskqueue', base64.b64encode('Hello world!'))
```

Source is here. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-queue/azure/storage/queue/models.py

Other options include binary_base64encode, and text_xmlencode etc., depending on what encoding your data use.

Comment: Setting the encode function was correct but after that I simply needed to call put_message with a string: `queue_service.put_message('taskqueue', 'Hello world!')` and allow the queue_service to handling encoding.

Comment: Your first approach works, but introduces unnecessary compute cycles (note the encode/decode cycle).

The correct way - and correct answer - for the original question is to set the encode_function of the of the QueueService to the correct encoding.

Comment: can you help on this post?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649998/poison-queue-content-into-main-queue/62653061#62653061

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is encoding format. The default encoding format of python is "ASCII", whereas the message needs to be encoded in base-64 format before putting into queue. The following code did the work.

```
from azure.storage import QueueService
import base64
queue_service = QueueService(account_name, account_key)
queue_service.put_message('taskqueue', base64.b64encode('Hello world!'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it gives the error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

Comment: @Arklur This wont work because in python 3 the default encoding is Utf-8. I post a solution as another answer.

Comment: Can you help on this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62649998/poison-queue-content-into-main-queue/62653061#62653061