# Python Azure Queue, getting error

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, base64, azure-storage-queues

I am struggling with an encoding issue. I am still trying to figure out the Python3 encoding scheme. I am trying to upload a json object from Python into an Azure Queue. I am using Python3

I make the json object

```
response = {"UserImageId": 636667744866847370, "OutputImageName": "car-1807177_with_blue-2467336_size_1020_u38fa38.png"} 
queue_service.put_message(response_queue, json.dumps(response))
```

When it gets to the queue, I get the error

```
{"imgResponse":"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ","log":null,"$return":""}
```

So I have to do something else, because apparently I need to base64 encode my string. So I try

```
queue_service.put_message(response_queue, base64.b64encode(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8')))
```

and I get

```
TypeError: message should be of type str
```

From the Azure Storage Queue package. If I check the type of the above statement, it is of type bytes (makes sense).
So my question is, how do I encode my json object into something that the queue service will understand. I would really like to be able to keep the _ and - and . characters in the image name.

Comment: `base64.b64encode(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do all of that encode+decode. Rather, change your message encoding format to Base64, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51142165/272109) to a very similar question. You can see all of the encode/decode format options on [this doc page](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-python/ref/azure.storage.queue.models.html#azure.storage.queue.models.QueueMessageFormat).

Comment: It is confusing. Can't call base64.b64encode('Hello world!') like the poster in that question in python3. If that would work then I would never have wrote this question.
I also respect the links to the docs page, but those docs make no sense to me.

Comment: @aaron - Did you also set the `encode_function` as shown in that other answer?

Comment: @DavidMakogon adding `queue_service.encode_function = QueueMessageFormat.text_base64encode` simplified things for me. Allows to use the json.dumps(my_dict) output without needing to do any Python encoding. Thank you for pointing that line out. I had overlooked it initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what I had to do in my code to make it work:

```
queue_service = QueueService(account_name=os.getenv('storageAccount'), account_key=os.getenv('storageKey'))
queue_service.encode_function = QueueMessageFormat.text_base64encode
```

after that I could just put messages:

```
queue_service.put_message('bbbb', message) # 'bbbb' is a queue name
```

Comment: This allowed me to `queue_service.put_message(response_queue, json.dumps(response))` which is preferable!

Answer (score 10):

If anyone is looking to solve this problem using QueueClient rather than QueueService, here is what worked for me:

```
import json
from azure.storage.queue import QueueServiceClient, QueueClient, QueueMessage, TextBase64EncodePolicy

conn_string = '[YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING_HERE]'
queue_client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(
    conn_string,
    '[QUEUE_NAME_HERE]',
    message_encode_policy=TextBase64EncodePolicy()
)
queue_client.send_message(json.dumps({'a':'b'}))
```

Comment: I had to set it like this. `queue_client.message_encode_policy = TextBase64EncodePolicy()` had no effect!