# Poison Queue content into main queue

Tags: azure-queues

I am trying to move poison messages into the main queue. I am not facing any problem in moving the messages, but looks like message is getting converted to some other encryption level.

```
<bound method DictMixin.values of {'id': '389a834e-48af-41b5-be36-5f61ad7c2232', 'inserted_on': 
datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 30, 3, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 
'expires_on': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 7, 3, 13, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
'dequeue_count': 0, 'content': 
'eyJjYWxsX2JhY2tfdXJpIjogImh0dHBzOi8vcG9zdG1hbi1lY2hvLmNvbS9wb3N0IiwgInBpcGVsaW5lX3J1bl
 9pZCI6ICI3OTY1MGU3Zi01NmFmLTRiYzgtOWE3NC0yYTk3YWRhOWRhNWUiLCAiZXhlY
 3V0aW9uX2lkIjogImRmYzcwMjAwLTY3MzgtNDNkMy1',
 'pop_receipt': None, 'next_visible_on': None}>
```

how can I convert content into the message queue ?

Answer (score 1):

As version 1.4.1 of the [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) doesn’t have the ability to move messages from one Azure queue to another.

Here is a simple [solution](https://mitchwheat.com/2018/09/11/azure-queues-retry-poison-messages/) to transfer poison messages back to the originating queue.  Obviously, you'll need to have fixed the error that caused the messages to end up in the poison message queue!

You’ll need to add a NuGet package reference to [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) :

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
 
void Main()
{
    const string queuename = "MyQueueName";
 
    string storageAccountString = "xxxxxx";
 
    RetryPoisonMesssages(storageAccountString, queuename);
}
 
private static int RetryPoisonMesssages(string storageAccountString, string queuename)
{
    CloudQueue targetqueue = GetCloudQueueRef(storageAccountString, queuename);
    CloudQueue poisonqueue = GetCloudQueueRef(storageAccountString, queuename + "-poison");
 
    int count = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var msg = poisonqueue.GetMessage();
        if (msg == null)
            break;
 
        poisonqueue.DeleteMessage(msg);
        targetqueue.AddMessage(msg);
        count++;
    }
 
    return count;
}
 
private static CloudQueue GetCloudQueueRef(string storageAccountString, string queuename)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageAccountString);
    CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queuename);
 
    return queue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using python. Is there any reference for python ?